# thread with delegate and anonymous function

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0

I am new to C# and .Net.
There is this code:

```
var loadInfoThread = new Thread(delegate() { try {..} catch(Exception e) {..}}); }  
loadInfoThread.Start();
```

This launch new worker thread that run anonymous method? meaning that then variables inside the method will be cleared when thread finishes the job?

What the `delegate()` does exactly?

Comment: Anonymous methods were training wheels for the much more expressive lambda expression syntax, available since C# version 3.  You might want to focus on them instead in your favorite C# language book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass any method to `Thread` constuctor beside the anonymous method ([delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900fyy8e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)). The variables in anonymous method will be cleared in the same way with normal function.

Thread without anonymous method.

```
var loadInfoThread = new Thread(SomeFun);
loadInfoThread.Start();      

private void SomeFun(){
{    
  try {

  } 
  catch(Exception e) {..}   
}
```

Comment: you can choose if you want to write a method that does the work, or do it anonymously with delegate() {}. For readability purposes I'd follow Adils proposal

Comment: OK, so when sending anonymous method to thread it must be with delegate() before the function so that the thread would know the memory address of newly created function ? the flow is like: create anynmous function in memory, send the function address to thread, when thread start it will get the function location and run it.

Comment: Yes, I think so, you can see in my answer SomeFun name is passed in Thread constructor instead of delegate.